# How do I assign the value I queried to a String which is an argument in a procedure if the argument's data type is an Object?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I made this procedure to help me re-use a select query:

```
Private Sub selectQry(ByVal myColumn As String, ByVal myTable As String, ByVal myFilter As String, ByVal myObjectOne As Object, ByVal myObj As Object)
    Dim qrySlctCaldate As String = "SELECT " + myColumn + " FROM " + myTable + " WHERE " + myFilter + " = '" & Replace(myObjectOne, "'", "''") & "'"
    Dim cmdSlct As New SqlCommand(qrySlctCaldate, transConn.Connection)


    Dim readSCalDate As SqlDataReader
    readSCalDate = cmdSlct.ExecuteReader

    While readSCalDate.Read
        If TypeOf (myObj) Is TextBox Or TypeOf (myObj) Is ComboBox Then
            myObj.Text = readSCalDate.Item(myColumn).ToString
        Else
            myObj = readSCalDate.Item(myColumn).ToString

        End If
    End While
    readSCalDate.Close()
```

And I use it like this if I would want the selected value placed in a textbox and it works fine

```
selectQry("ProcConvDescription", "Line", "LineCode", nameValue.Value, txtProcess)
```

However if I want the value to be passed in a string like so:

```
 selectQry("LastCalibrationDate", "EquipmentItem", "ControlNo", txtControlNo.Text, strCalDate)
```

The string ends up having an empty string value. How do I assign the value I queried to that String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your method to be a function returning the string rather than trying to assign it inside the function.

```
Private Function selectQry(ByVal myColumn As String, ByVal myTable As String, 
                           ByVal myFilter As String, ByVal myObjectOne As Object
                          ) As String
    Dim qrySlctCaldate As String = _
        String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = '{3}'",
                      myColumn, myTable, myFilter,
                      Replace(myObjectOne, "'", "''"))
    Dim cmdSlct As New SqlCommand(qrySlctCaldate, transConn.Connection)

    Using readSCalDate As SqlDataReader = cmdSlct.ExecuteReader
        While readSCalDate.Read
            Return readSCalDate.Item(myColumn).ToString
        End While
    End Using
End Sub

txtProcess.Text = selectQry("ProcConvDescription", "Line", "LineCode", nameValue.Value)
strCalDate = selectQry("LastCalibrationDate", "EquipmentItem", "ControlNo", txtControlNo.Text)
```

Also, I would highly recommend turning on Option Strict to get better type safety.

Comment: Why I did not think this of this is beyond me. Thank you! But how come I can't assign the value to the obj which is a string

Comment: @Kurusu The assignment you were doing is only applying to the local variable.  To affect the calling method's variable, you need to pass ByRef as Bryce suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing myObj by reference:

```
ByRef myObj As Object)
```

...and see if that helps.

And while I do see the value of being able to build this query dynamically, you should really adjust your WHERE clause to use sql parameters instead (protects against SQL injection).

```
" WHERE " + myFilter + " = @objectOne "
cmdSlct.Parameters.Clear()
cmdSlct.Parameters.AddWithValue("objectOne",myObjectOne)
```