# How to assign a value to a variable of type Double, that has been passed as Object?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to assign a value to global variable, which has a `Property` of type `Double`. This `Property` is passed as `Object` and the assignment fails.

In the example code below, the value is never assigned to the actual object, but only locally:

```
Public Class Form1
    Friend Home As New Building

    Private Sub AssignValues() Handles Me.Load
        'Objects of different types are added to a list
        Dim listObjects As New List(Of Object)
        listObjects.Add(Home.Surface)

        'All the Objects in listObjects are assigned a value that
        'is stored as String
        For Each o As Object In listObjects
            SetProperty(o, "45.6")
            Debug.Print("Surface = " & Home.Surface.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetProperty(ByRef Variable As Object, ByVal Value As String)
        Select Case Variable.GetType
            Case GetType(Double)
                Variable = CDbl(Value)
            Case Else
                '...
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Building
    Dim _surface As Double = 0
    Public Property Surface As Double
        Get
            Return _surface
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _surface = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The program invariably outputs `Surface = 0` instead of `45.6`. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to pass the `Variable` as reference, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386323/1458491), but without success. I also read about [using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131972/reference-label1-text-as-object), but there ought to be something simpler than that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your adding home.surface to the list, your adding a copy of the double to the list and then adjusting that copy. Stick a watch on "o" and see how it changes whilst home.surface remains the same.

If you want to use reflection, try something along these lines.

```
Dim prop As Reflection.PropertyInfo = o.GetType().GetProperty("Surface")
prop.SetValue(o, 45.6)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible not add a copy of the double to my list, but the double itself, or a reference to it?

Comment: You could add a reference to "Home" but as far as I'm aware you cannot add a reference to a value type.

Comment: Ok, so I either have to use reflection or to change the structure of the objects I'm passing so that they are not value types any more. I think I'll try the second option first. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

With `Variable.GetType` you will get always `Object`, because this is the type of `Variable`. What you can do with an `Object` is converting/casting it into a different type (like `Double`).

The best way to determine the "original type" from where the `Object` comes would be including an additional variable telling it. Another option might be converting the given `Object` into the target `Type` and see if it is not nothing/does not trigger an error. But this second option is not too accurate, mainly when dealing with "equivalent types" like Doubles/Integers.

Comment: That seems actually not to be true. When I run the code above, the `Case GetType(Double)` is entered.

Comment: Originally, I tested it with VS 2008 and it was impossible to even compile the project. Right now I am testing it with VS 2010 and you are right!? I don't know what to say; this is not the logical/expected/ideal behaviour but seems to work fine on this specific context. But also it is not clear why the property is not set rightly. What is clear is that object = CDbl(Value) cannot be right you have to do object = value and then convert object to double. By doing this in VS 2010, I get the right value for o (25.4), with your code I get 254.

Comment: PS: I can delete my answer if you wish. But independently upon what VB does internally, theoretically your code is doing something wrong; if you don't get an error is because VB (in VS 2010, not before) corrects it automatically.

Comment: I find it actually really interesting to learn that this code does not work under VS2008. I am, yes, using VS2010. And you're right also that the `CDbl()` actually converts the value from `45.6` to `456`. And no error or warning is displayed, even with ' Option Explicit On`. Only one thing here is sure: I can't keep that code :-)

Comment: Better doing things right rather than expecting VB to correct problems. VB over-corrects much more than other languages and this is certainly nice although might become a bit dangerous some times. Anyway... happy to have been of some help.